# Como generar un nuevo array en esta situación

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en JavaScript y tengo una duda de como poder implementar .map en este caso.

Me plantee el ejercicio de hacer una fusión de dos arreglos sin usar métodos o el spread operator.

```
function fusionarArreglos(arrBase, arrComplemento) {
for(let i = 0; i < arrComplemento.length; i++){
    arrBase.push(arrComplemento[i])
 }
};
```

Mi duda es ¿cómo puedo utilizar .map en este caso para no modificar el "arrBase" o como podría crear un nuevo arreglo que no modifique los que recibo por parámetros en mi función?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:

Ya puede aplicar el .map, ahora estoy intentando sacar la variable, porque creo que al declarar con let solo existe en el bloque, quizás la solución más fácil es usar var y listo

Este es el código completo:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function fusionarArreglos(arrBase, arrComplemento) {

    let nuevoArreglo = arrBase.map((elementos) => elementos);
    
        for(let i = 0; i < arrComplemento.length; i++){
            nuevoArreglo.push(arrComplemento[i])
        }

    return nuevoArreglo;
};

fusionarArreglos(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: ¿Y de qué elementos se llena ese nuevo array?

Comment: Quiero tomar el array que estoy generando en fusionarArreglor() y colocarlo en el nuevo array. Así no modifico ninguno y conservo los 2 anteriores intactos

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) no modifica el arreglo, solo **crea uno nuevo**. El tamaño del nuevo arreglo es igual al arreglo original, probablemente se pueda cambiar ese comportamiento, pero no lo recomiendo pues se violaría la intención de `map`

Comment: Correcto. Por eso quiero usar map, para crear un nuevo arreglo. Porque mi función modifica el arreglo que sea "arrBase". Entonces cuando quiera ir al arreglo original no podría porque mi función lo modifico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente luego de horas de pensamiento. Di con una posible solución que me funciono. Muchas gracias a todos los que respondieron

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function fusionarArreglos(arrBase, arrComplemento) {

    let nuevoArreglo = arrBase.map((elementos) => elementos);
    
        for(let i = 0; i < arrComplemento.length; i++){
            nuevoArreglo.push(arrComplemento[i])
        }
    
    return nuevoArreglo;
};

let ArrayFusionado = fusionarArreglos(arr1, arr2);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(ArrayFusionado);
```

Answer (score 4):

Tratando de simplificar un poco la teoría sobre asignación en *Javascript*: Cuando asignas objetos (o arreglos) existentes a una variable, lo que realmente pasa es que obtienes un apuntador de memoria para ese recurso y, si modificas "la copia", también se modificará el original porque, a pesar de ser distintas variables, ocupan el  mismo espacio en memoria.

Los parámetros enviados a una función, son recibidos como valor, cuando es tipo de datos primitivo (entero, punto flotante, cadena, etc.), pero funciona diferente con los objetos y creo que es un tema extenso para exponerlo en una respuesta. A modo de resumen: "el problema" que presenta tu función está relacionado a lo expuesto en el primer párrafo.

La solución es crear una copia que, para este caso, puedes usar [array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) sin parámetros, que devolverá un **nuevo arreglo** con todos los valores del original.

```js
function fusionarArreglos(arrBase, arrComplemento) {
    // Crear copia del arreglo
    let arrRet = arrBase.slice();
    for(let i = 0; i < arrComplemento.length; i++){
        arrRet.push(arrComplemento[i])
    }
    // Devolver arreglo
    return arrRet;
};

let arr1 = [0, 5, 8, 12];
let arr2 = [3,7, 21];

let fusionado = fusionarArreglos(arr1, arr2);
// arr1 no se modifica
console.log(arr1, fusionado);
```

Comment: Es correcto para no modificar el objeto debo crear una copia y esa copia es la que modifico. Esto viene de ver la Cocina del Código donde explican eso y de un curso que estoy tomando. No pensé en slice, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres fusionar arreglos sin metodos ni nada, lo mas viable seria haciendo una concatenacion. Respecto a lo del .map tienes que entender primeramente muy bien su funcion porque en el codigo que compartiste no hay como usarlo, ya que precisamente eso, no tienes ningun arreglo, y respecto a los datos ingresados por arrBase y arrComplemento eso ya seria otro tema en cuanto a como manipular esos "argumentos". Por ultimo para poder fusionar arreglos, tienes que tener variables que guarden sus respectivos datos y de nuevo en tu codigo no hay arreglos.

Te recomiendo veas este link que es la documentacion oficial de javascript para que entiendas lo de .map.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

y aca abajo te cito la parte mas parecida que encontre respecto a lo que buscas de fusionar esos arreglos con una funcion.

```
var numeros = [1, 4, 9];
var dobles  = numeros.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});

// dobles es ahora [2, 8, 18]
// numeros sigue siendo [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Entiendo. Esa es la documentación que siempre consulto primero. Ahora usar concatenación con qué? La idea de este ejercicio que me platee es tener un arreglo unidimensional. Sin métodos no se que podría aplicar. En la función recibo arreglos. Si creo dos arreglos cualquiera los paso como parámetros los fusiona que es mi propósito. Intente hacerlo desde la declaración del arreglo como tal pero me genera un undefined.

Comment: Es un poco confuso de igual manera, comparte absolutamente todo el codigo que estas escribiendo y seguimos mirando.

Comment: Hola, acabo de actualizar